# C# Type Comparison: Type.Equals vs operator ==

Tags: c#, types, comparison-operators

ReSharper suggests that the following be changed from:

```
Type foo = typeof( Foo );
Type bar = typeof( Bar );

if( foo.Equals( bar ) ) { ... }
```

To:

```
if( foo == bar ) { ... }
```

**operator ==**

```
// Summary:
//     Indicates whether two System.Type objects are equal.
//
// Parameters:
//   left:
//     The first object to compare.
//
//   right:
//     The second object to compare.
//
// Returns:
//     true if left is equal to right; otherwise, false.
public static bool operator ==( Type left, Type right );
```

**Equals( Type o )**

```
// Summary:
//     Determines if the underlying system type of the current System.Type is the
//     same as the underlying system type of the specified System.Type.
//
// Parameters:
//   o:
//     The System.Type whose underlying system type is to be compared with the underlying
//     system type of the current System.Type.
//
// Returns:
//     true if the underlying system type of o is the same as the underlying system
//     type of the current System.Type; otherwise, false.
public virtual bool Equals( Type o );
```

**Question**
Why would `operator ==` be recommended over `Equals( Type o )` when comparing Types?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I suggest that you read the excellent [When is a Type not a Type?](https://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/02/when-is-a-type-not-a-type.html) blog post by Brad Wilson. To summarize: a runtime type (represented by the internal type RuntimeType), managed by the CLR, is not always the same as a `Type`, which can be extended. `Equals` will check the [underlying system type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.underlyingsystemtype#System_Type_UnderlyingSystemType), whereas `==` will check the type itself.

A simple example:

```
Type type = new TypeDelegator(typeof(int));
Console.WriteLine(type.Equals(typeof(int))); // Prints True
Console.WriteLine(type == typeof(int));      // Prints False
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is simple: The two are functionally equivalent in this case and the latter is more readable.

Comment: R# will typically suggest something and provide a valid reason; in this case if they are functionally equivalent, I have doubts that the suggestion is for readability, which is subjective. I wonder if there is another reason it is being suggested?

Comment: @MetroSmurf - R# often suggests things for the sake of readability (reducing nesting in if statements, for example).

Comment: That is quite probably the intended reason, but as the two are not functionally equivalent in this case, then surely this is a mistake in Resharper?

Answer (score -2):

From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/29/when-should-i-use-and-when-should-i-use-equals.aspx

> The Equals method is just a virtual one defined in System.Object, and
>   overridden by whichever classes choose to do so. The == operator is an
>   operator which can be overloaded by classes, but which usually has
>   identity behaviour.
>
> For reference types where == has not been overloaded, it compares
>   whether two references refer to the same object - which is exactly
>   what the implementation of Equals does in System.Object.
>
> Value types do not provide an overload for == by default. However,
>   most of the value types provided by the framework provide their own
>   overload. The default implementation of Equals for a value type is
>   provided by ValueType, and uses reflection to make the comparison,
>   which makes it significantly slower than a type-specific
>   implementation normally would be. This implementation also calls
>   Equals on pairs of references within the two values being compared.
>
> However, the main difference between the two types of comparison in
>   normal use (where you're unlikely to be defining your own value types
>   very often) is polymorphism. Operators are overloaded, not overridden,
>   which means that unless the compiler knows to call the more specific
>   version, it'll just call the identity version.

Comment: This answer tells us nothing about how instances of the `Type` class define `Equals` and `==`. So I don't see how this is a useful answer to the question. Is this answer based on *misreading* the question?