# .NET Windows Store Apps and System.Type - equivalent to operator ==?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps, equality, system.type

According to the accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9234009/650012) StackOverflow question, there is a difference between the `System.Type.Equals` method and the `System.Type operator ==`:

```
a runtime type (represented by the internal type RuntimeType), managed by 
the CLR is not always the same as a Type, which can be extended. Equals 
will check the underlying system type, whereas == will check the type itself.
```

In *.NET for Windows Store Apps*, the [System.Type operator ==](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.op_equality.aspx) is not available.

How can I completely reproduce the functionality of the `System.Type operator ==` in a *Windows Store application*? Or, is the specific equality operator functionality for `System.Type` not relevant in *Windows Store apps*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the underlying principle here is that `Equals` is a virtual instance method of every type, meaning it will use the vtable to determine the implementation to use, at runtime, based on the type of the actual object that called `Equals` (disregarding the type of the variable).

`operator ==` can be thought of as a static method (with a lot of overloads).  It is not virtual, so the implementation that is referred to will be based on the compile time type of the variable holding the object, and won't be based on what the actual type of the object is at runtime.

This behavior can be replicated by simply creating your own `static` `Equals` methods (on whatever type or types you prefer) that behave based on the types of the two arguments.  This is slightly less convenient to type out than using `operator ==`, but does effectively the same thing once compiled.

Comment: Many thanks for this very informative answer, Servy. Now I just have to move on to see how I can apply this in my project :-)

Comment: @AndersGustafsson It's rather straghtforward.  You just need to have a static `Equals` method for every type you need to compare in this manor, in which the two arguments it accepts are of that type.  You also need to *not* call the virtual `Equals` instance method within your static method, because if it's overridden you'll lose your desired behavior.

Comment: The specifics are that I am thinking of porting an existing third-party library. I am not yet sure, but potentially the issue applies to relatively many classes. Ideally I do not want to end up writing new `Equals` methods for a large number of classes "just to be on the safe side". But anyway, this is outside the scope of my question, I need to dig deeper into the project to get a grip on things. In any case, I am very grateful for your prompt and informative response, many thanks once again.