# Catch base exception class but not its derived generic variants

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I don't catch generic FaultException in my client.

My Service Contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IEmpresaWebService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(ValidationExceptionDTO))]
    EmpleadoEmpresaDTO Login(string username, string password);
}
```

My Service

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)] 
public class EmpresaWebService : IEmpresaWebService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _UnitOfWork;

    public EmpresaWebService(IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork) {
        this._UnitOfWork = UnitOfWork;
        //SeedingBootsrapper.RegisterSeedings();
        //var initializer = new CustomDataInitializer<PsicotecnicosContext>(new string[] { "*" });
        //Database.SetInitializer<PsicotecnicosContext>(initializer);
    }

    public EmpleadoEmpresaDTO Login(string username, string password) {
        var EmpleadoEmpresaService = this._UnitOfWork.GetService<EmpleadoEmpresaService>();
        EmpleadoEmpresaDTO empleadoEmpresaDTO = new EmpleadoEmpresaDTO();
        try {
            var empleado = EmpleadoEmpresaService.ValidarLogin(username, password);
            Mapper.CreateMap<EmpleadoEmpresa, EmpleadoEmpresaDTO>();
            empleadoEmpresaDTO = Mapper.Map<EmpleadoEmpresa, EmpleadoEmpresaDTO>(empleado);
        }
        catch (ValidationException Ex) {
            throw new FaultException<ValidationExceptionDTO>(new ValidationExceptionDTO(Ex.Errors));
        }
        return empleadoEmpresaDTO;
    }
}
```

the class that try serialize

```
[DataContract]
public class ValidationExceptionDTO
{
    [DataMember]
    private Dictionary<string, string> _errors = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public ValidationExceptionDTO(IList<ValidationFailure> Errors) {
        foreach (var validation in Errors) {
            this._errors.Add(validation.ErrorMessage, validation.PropertyName);
        }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<string,string> Errors {
        get {
            if (this._errors != null) {
                return this._errors;
            }
            else {
                return new Dictionary<string,string>();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my client:

```
public class CuentasController : Controller
{

    // GET: /Candidatos/Cuentas/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Login() {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(string username, string password, bool recordarme) {
        try {
            EmpresaServiceProxy.EmpresaWebServiceClient client = new EmpresaServiceProxy.EmpresaWebServiceClient();
            EmpleadoEmpresaDTO empleadoEmpresa = client.Login(username, password);

            var AutenticationProvider = new AuthenticationProvider(this.HttpContext);
            AutenticationProvider.LoginAs(username, recordarme);
        }
        catch (FaultException<ValidationExceptionDTO> ex) {

        }
        catch(FaultException ex){
            //only cath here
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)  {
            return RedirectToAction("Prueba");
        }
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize]
    public string Prueba() {
        return "Esta logeado";
    }

}
```

}

Comment: I didn't catch what your question/problem is. Could you elaborate a little more about what you are trying to do and where it is breaking?

Comment: I try catch Exception in my client,  but only catch FaultException and not FaultException<ValidationExceptionDTO>

Comment: It's not clear what _is_ happening and what you _want_ to happen.  With the code you have `FaultException<ValidationExceptionDTO>` exceptions will get swallowed (it won't be caught "again" by the next `catch` block).

Comment: I want catch FaultException<ValidationExceptionDTO> but always catch FaultException.

Comment: @MartinSanchez Do not post everything you have in the question - walls of code are very difficult to read, post only [relevant compact code pieces](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, if it is difficult to describe desired behaviour using intricate phrasings, then describe it using case scenarios: like if it throw `FaultException` it is handled in `try(FaultException)`, if it throws `FaultException<ValidationExceptionDTO>`, then it is being handled in both the `try(FaultException<ValidationExceptionDTO>)` and `try(FaultException)`, or whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Standard C# exception Handling code won't allow you to do it, so you will have to catch all `FaultExceptions` and filter them using [GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx) method and strict [Type comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234009/c-sharp-type-comparison-type-equals-vs-operator):

```
   catch(FaultException ex)
   {
        if (ex.GetType().Equals(typeof(FaultException))) // Strict comparison of type
        {
            // Handle only FaultException exceptions, not its descendants
        }
        else
            throw;
    }
```

Just do not forget to throw(or do not throw depending on your requirements) the exception (Thanks @DStanley)

Comment: Don't forget to rethrow unhandled exceptions or they'll get swallowed.