# Type comparison at design time fails until I restart Visual Studio

Tags: c#, design-time

I have written a class library that needs to get info from the project that references it at design-time. I want to get the type of the class in the project that inherits from the abstract class `Deklaration` in the class library. In this case it would be `Variablen`

This works very well most of the time, the function `GetAssembly()` returns the correct assembly, and in most cases `GetMyDeclaration()` returns the correct type.

Code from the library:

```
   /// <summary>
    /// Get the assembly where the vars are declared in
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Assembly GetAssembly()
    {
        Assembly[] assemblys = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

        foreach (Assembly assembly in assemblys)
            if (assembly.EntryPoint != null)
                if (!assembly.FullName.Contains("vshost"))
                    return assembly;

        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the container where all the vars are declarated in (inherited from clas "Deklaration"
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Type GetMyDeclaration()
    {
        Assembly myAssembly = GetAssembly();

        if (myAssembly != null)
            foreach (Type declaration in myAssembly.GetTypes())
                if (declaration.BaseType == typeof(Deklaration))//1st point where I get stuck, can be fixed with .FullName comparison
                    return declaration;

        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the declaring fieldinfo of the given object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ojb"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static FieldInfo MyField(object ojb)
    {
        Type myDeclaration = GetMyDeclaration();

        if (myDeclaration == null)
            return null;

        foreach (FieldInfo field in myDeclaration.GetFields())
            if (field.GetValue(null) == ojb)//2nd point where I get stuck
                return field;

        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the full name of the declaration of an object like "HMI.Variablen.M0_0"
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string FullName(object obj)
    {
        var field = MyField(obj);

        if (field == null)
            return "Restart Visual Studio!";

        return field.DeclaringType.FullName + "." + field.Name;
    }
```

Code from the project:

```
public class Variablen : Deklaration
{
    public static BOOL M0_0 = new BOOL("DB100.DBX0.0");//Full Name: HMI.Variablen.M0_0
    public static BOOL M0_1 = new BOOL("DB100.DBX0.1");//Full Name: HMI.Variablen.M0_1
    public static BOOL M0_2 = new BOOL("DB100.DBX0.2");//...
    public static BOOL M0_3 = new BOOL("DB100.DBX0.3");
    public static BOOL M0_4 = new BOOL("DB100.DBX0.3");
    public static BOOL M0_5 = new BOOL("DB100.DBX0.4");
    public static BOOL M0_7 = new BOOL("DB100.DBX0.4");
}
```

Everything works fine until I modify the class `Variablen` in my Project and rebuild it (add a new declaration or Change an existing)

After that, the line `if (t.BaseType == typeof(Deklaration))` always returns "false". Debugging shows that `a.GetTypes()` returns `Variablen' with BaseType`Deklaration` but the the type-comparison Fails.

I assume that this has to do something with incosistency, but rebuilding or cleaning the solution doesnt help.

When I restart VisualStudio everything is OK (just closing and opening the soultion  doesnt work)

Can I optimize my Code?
Or maybe is there a function I can call to "refresh" or "clear" Visual Studio?

**UPDATE**

This is reqally about "destroyed" references. Even if I get the comparison working with

```
if (t.BaseType.FullName == typeof(Deklaration).FullName)
```

I will get more problems a few steps later, when comparing references.

```
  private FieldInfo MyField()
  {
        Type t = BASE.GetMyDeclaration();

        if (t == null)
            return null;

        foreach (FieldInfo i in t.GetFields())
            if (i.GetValue(null) == this) //never gets true after compile
                return i;

        return null;
    }
```

So in my opinion only a reset or reload of Visual Studio will work. Would be cool if I could let the code do this automatically when an error occurs, but I dont know if there is a function for that...

This is also only an issue during designtime and only after compile. Afte a restart of Visual Studio or during execution there are no problems.

[Screenshot 1: BaseType](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMXyL.jpg)

[Screenshot 2: typeof(Deklaration)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZIMl.jpg)

Comment: It looks like GetAssembly returns a different copy of assembly than that your code runs against. Maybe Visual Studio leaves an old copy on the disk, which then accidentally gets picked up by the binder. So you compare two different types, named the same, but coming from two different assemblies.

Comment: You can compare references to Assembly objects returned by each type, in order to detect the mismatch.

Comment: @felix-b
You are totally right, if I use `return System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();` , the Problem is solved (partially). But I only can use this if I declare this method in the Project, not in the classlibrary :(

Comment: Seems I also have to change the assembly-info to this `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.*")]` (got that hint from an asp-forum) The * ensures the Compiler knows it has to refresh everything it seems

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your issue, but the type comparison seems to be a bit faulty, you shouldn't compare types with the `==` operator, because you might compare reference equality or actually the wrong RunTime Types.

You could try this

```
if (typeof(Deklaration).IsAssignableFrom(t))
```

If this doesn't work, you might also consider using a `TypeDelegator` instead of a normal Type comparison, since it's saver to use.

```
Type type = new TypeDelegator(typeof(int));
Console.WriteLine(type.Equals(typeof(int))); // Prints True
Console.WriteLine(type == typeof(int));      // Prints False
```

In your case probably:

```
Type type = new TypeDelegator(t);
type.BaseType.Equals(typeof (Deklaration));
```

I would suggest you make some `Console.WriteLine` debug outputs  with all those methods too see which ones are still returning the correct type for your case.

Some of the information here is from this SO Post:

[C# Type Comparison: Type.Equals vs operator ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234009/c-sharp-type-comparison-type-equals-vs-operator)

Comment: Thank you for your contributinon, will give it a try, when i an back at my PC

Comment: I have tried with comparison of .FullName earlier and that works, but then i get problems afterwards when trying to Assign a var of that type in the project with a var generated in the library... VS still thinks that its different types...